# Categorical feature as output and perform a classification

Tags: classification, regression, categorical-data

I have a database in which the output feature Y is categorical, for example (oversimplification)

```
A          B        C        Y
1.0        0.2      5.1      Car
3.0        1.1      0.1      Car
7.6        6.9      2.7      Bike
2.5        3.8      0.3      Train
6.1        9.5      8.4      Car
8.4        0.7      5.6      Train
```

and so on.......

I would like to run a classification algorithm like kNN, Logistic Regression or Random Forest using as the output feature the column Y, i.e., to predict which transport was used.

How could I implement that in python since the output is not numerical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that yours data are in pandas dataframe, you could use **Label Encoding**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df['Y'] = le.fit_transform(df['Y'])
#check labels
# le.inverse_transform(df['Y])
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking for is [scikit-learn's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) `LabelEncoder` which will transform categorical values (e.g. car, bike, motorbike) to numerical values (1, 2, 3).

In case you have also categorical variables as features (X-Values) in your data set, I recommend using `OneHotEncoder` or pandas implementation of `get_dummies()` when dealing with categories. `LabelEncoder` would imply an order of the features (e.g. responds to a survey "Would you buy Product A" - (1) Never, (2) Not likely, (3) Don't know, (4) Likely, (5) Yes)